# How can I exclude proftp authentication failure messages from logwatch?

Tags: logwatch

I use `logwatch` on my server, now I get thousands of these lines in the report email:

```
--------------------- pam_unix Begin ------------------------ 

 proftpd:
    Unknown Entries:
       check pass; user unknown: 339 Time(s)
       authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=::ffff:62.115.255.98 : 27 Time(s)
       authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=::ffff:188.102.152.23 : 7 Time(s)
...
```

I already have loglevel Low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit `/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf`

and add

```
Service = "-proftpd-messages"
Service = "-pam_unix"
```